# Pandas dataframe.at

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am doing a project for faculty and I am getting an error. I am new to this language and I am following some steps, but the book that I am reading is a bit old, so some functions are outdated and I can't manage to get over one error. I searched about the function dataframe.set_value  and I saw that this was changed to dataframe.at .

It goes like this :

```
for index, row in dataset.iterrows():
    home_team = row["Home"]
    visitor_team = row["Away"]
    row["HomeLastWin"]=won_last[home_team]
    dataset.at(index, "HomeLastWin") = won_last[home_team]
    dataset.at(index, "VisitorLastWin") = won_last[visitor_team]
    won_last[home_team] = int(row["HomeWin"])
    won_last[visitor_team] = 1 - int(row["HomeWin"])
```

The original code found in the book was:

```
dataset.set_value(index,"HomeLastWin", won_last[home_team])
```

I understood that the parameters are dataset.at(What_row,What_column) = change_with_this.

The error I am getting is this:

```
File "<ipython-input-40-acfeaead26ef>", line 7
    dataset.at(index, "HomeLastWin") = won_last[home_team]
    ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call
```

Thank you for your time and answers!

Comment: You're using round braces `.at()` but it needs to be square braces `.at[]`. It's a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See pandas documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html).

You're using `.at()`, but want to use square brackets with `.at[]`.

`dataset.at[index, "HomeLastWin"] = won_last[home_team]`